# writing an output iterator for c++20

Tags: c++, c++20

I'm looking for help in writing an output iterator that satisfies the std::output_iterator concept. The following iterator works under gcc and clang but fails with MSVC. The static_assert also fails on all compilers. gcc gives by far the most detailed information with `-fconcepts-diagnostics-depth=3` but unfortunately it's mostly greek to me. Does anyone know where to find good information on how to satisfy this concept?

```cpp
#include <iterator>
#include <iostream>

struct Outerator_ {
    int storage;
    using value_type = int;
    
    Outerator_() = default;
    Outerator_& operator++() {
        std::cout << "operator++ " << storage << " ";
        return *this;
    }
    Outerator_& operator++(int) {
        std::cout << "operator++ " << storage << " ";
        return *this;
    }
    int& operator*() {
        return storage;
    }
    void operator=(int i) { storage = i; }
    void operator=(int& i) { storage = i; }
};


static_assert(std::output_iterator<Outerator_, int>);
```

Comment: `++` on an iterator should return an iterator (or reference to one for pre-increment), just like they normally do on most types.

Comment: i've made that change but still have all the same compiler messages :(

Comment: `difference_type` or `operator-` is also missing.

Comment: `operator=` isn't needed. Writes through an iterator are indirect, through `operator*`. Also, the chosen overload set will be ambiguous for lvalue arguments. It doesn't make sense to overload by-value and by-reference for the same type. And neither is `Outerator_() = default;` required. It is implicitly-declared anyway as well.

Comment: To be safe, each time you implement an iterator, think hard what these internal types should be: `difference_type` `value_type` `pointer` (spoiler: `= void`) `reference` and `iterator_category`.

Answer (score 2):

You need to have a `difference_type` alias, and the right return types for the two `operator++` functions:

```cpp
struct Outerator_ {
    int storage;
    using difference_type = std::ptrdiff_t;

    Outerator_& operator++() {
        std::cout << "operator++ " << storage << " ";
        return *this;
    }
    Outerator_ operator++(int) {
        auto copy = *this;
        ++*this;
        return copy;
    }
    int& operator*() const { // doesn't have to be const, but nice to have
        return storage;
    }
};

// TODO: add constructors, assignment operators, and other things that
//       make this iterator more useful
```

*Note: you can remove `value_type` and the default constructor. The code above is the bare minimum to satisfy the `std::output_iterator` concept.*

Alternatively you could provide a binary `operator-`, but usually that's only done for random access iterators.
If you did that, `difference_type` would be inferred from the return type of the operator.

`difference_type` is necessary for functions like [`std::next`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/next), even when it's not possible to directly advance the iterator by N steps.

---

See [`std::back_insert_iterator`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/back_insert_iterator) for an example of an output iterator in the standard library.

Answer (score 1):

> Does anyone know where to find good information on how to satisfy this
> concept?

In the C++20 iterator system, the [`input_iterator`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/input_iterator) and [`output_iterator`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/output_iterator) are both built on top of the [`input_or_output_iterator`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/input_or_output_iterator) concept, which has the following definition

```
template<class I>
concept input_or_output_iterator =
  requires(I i) {
    { *i } -> /* can-reference */;
  } &&
  std::weakly_incrementable<I>;
```

That is, for a type to behave like an iterator, it must syntactically support `operator*()`, `operator++()`, and `operator++(int)` operations. The minimal type that satisfies `input_or_output_iterator` is as follows

```
struct I_or_O {
  using difference_type = int;
  I_or_O& operator++();
  void operator++(int);
  int operator*();
};

static_assert(input_or_ouput_iterator<I_or_O>);
```

Note that such type is still required to have a valid `difference_type`, as this is the information required by a series of manipulation functions operating on `input_or_ouput_iterator` (such as [`ranges::advance`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/ranges/advance)).

---

The `input_iterator` concept is refined based on `input_or_ouput_iterator`

```
template<class I>
  concept input_iterator =
    input_or_output_iterator<I> &&
    indirectly_readable<I> &&
    ...
```

Among them, `indirectly_readable` requires that type `I` must have a valid `value_type` and its `operator*()` must be `const`-qualified, so the minimum type is changed to

```
struct I {
  using difference_type = int;
  using value_type = int;
//      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  I& operator++();
  void operator++(int);
  value_type operator*() const;
//                       ^^^^^
};

static_assert(input_iterator<I>);
```

---

Now, back to your question, let's look at the definition of `output_iterator`

```
template<class I, class T>
  concept output_iterator =
    input_or_output_iterator<I> &&
    indirectly_writable<I, T> &&
    requires(I i, T&& t) {
      *i++ = std::forward<T>(t);   /* not required to be equality-preserving */
    };
```

Taking `T` as `int` as an example, what do we ask for an output iterator of type `int`? Well, `indirectly_writable` requires that the return type of `operator*()` is assignable from `int`, which is the *output* part, and the `requires`-clause further checks that the `operator++(int)` returns something that also is dereferenced.

Therefore, compared to the `input_or_output_iterator`, the return type of post-increment of the iterator that satisfies `output_iterator` cannot be `void`. In the vast majority of cases, we just return the iterator type

```
struct O {
  using difference_type = int;
  O& operator++();
  O operator++(int);
//^
  int& operator*();
//   ^
};

static_assert(output_iterator<O, int>);
```

So for your `Outerator_` class, adding a `difference_type` member type to it is enough to satisfy all the syntax checks of `output_iterator`. Additionally, post-increment should return a copy rather than a reference to itself to comply with its meaning.